# Plotting non-standard axes

Tags: python, matplotlib, coordinate-systems, axes, imshow

I am plotting an image using RA and Dec coordinates.
The image overlaps the (RA, Dec) = (0,0) point. For the y-axis (Declination) this is fine, but for the x-axis, working in degrees, I am finding it difficult to plot this properly.

I want the plot to start at (RA, Dec) = (358, -2) and span four square degrees up to (2, 2).
Is there a way to get python/matplotlib to understand that 360 degrees = 0 degrees on the x-axis?

This is how I started:

```
lowerleft_ra = 358.
lowerleft_dec = -2.
lx = lowerleft_ra
ly = lowerleft_dec
uy = lowerleft_dec + 4.
ux = lowerleft_ra + 4.

plt.imshow(image, origin = 'lower', extent = [lx, ux, ly, uy])
```

This makes the x-axis span from 358 to 362, which is not what I am looking for.
I then tried modifying it as follows:

```
if lowerleft_ra + 4. > 360.:
    ux = lowerleft_ra + 4. - 360.
else:
    ux = lowerleft_ra + 4.
```

But this just sets the x-axis running in reverse order from 358 down to 2 deg.

How can I get it to go 358, 359, 0, 1, 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The extents information passed to `imshow` is informing matplotlib about the size of the object you're plotting (scale, ratio, etc). Once you have plotted it you are free to adjust the axes manually. While I don't think you can tell matplotlib to plot an axis with non-linear values, you *can* replace the tick labels.

I suggest creating a scale that goes from -2 to +2 and then using the following method to apply the tick labels to your liking:

```
plt.xticks([-2,-1,0,1,2], [358,359,0,1,2])
```

Or using the API

```
ax.set_xticks([-2,-1,0,1,2])
ax.set_xticklabels([358,359,0,1,2])
```

This gives me the following plot:

[image]